# implode() generated string inserting only first element of the array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, string

I am trying to insert array into database but it only insert first element of the array

This is my input field

```
<input required="true" name="aprice[]" type="text">
```

and receiving on another page in post

```
$aprice= implode(",",$_POST['aprice']);
```

This is my insert query

```
 $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `products` (`aprice`) VALUES (?)");
 $stmt->bind_param("s", $aprice);
 $stmt->execute();
```

Here if I entered 1,2,3 then it will insert only 1 in database

**I tried**

Here I trying to implode whole array into a string like '1,2,3'

```
$aprice= " ' ".implode(",",$_POST['aprice'])." ' ";
```

another way

```
'['.implode(",",$_POST['aprice']).']';
```

But both are not working

Comment: Var_dump `$_POST['aprice']` or better yet `$_POST` and edit your question to include what the output is

Comment: In general you shouldn't store things in a database as a list, you should have a separate row for each value.

Comment: Do not store comma-separated values in the database. This is going to be a nightmare later on.

Comment: `aprice` is probably of type int, is it? In that case you cannot store a string in there.

Answer (score 0):

I achieve this by simply **changing type int to varchar in phpmyadmin** and with the following code:

```
$aprice= implode(",",$_POST['aprice']);
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `products` (`aprice`) VALUES (?)");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $aprice);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: If you're going to change the database, you should fix it to be normalized.